# How to Link External libraries in c++(windows 10) using command line?

Tags: c++, command-line, mingw

after google search, I came up with this Solution

```
 g++ finlename.cpp -I{include file directory address} -L{Library file directory address} 
   -l(linkeroptions)
```

seems like this doesn't work for me. when I compile using this I get an error stating:- cannot find the headername.h(header file that was included in my program of the external lib).

file:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***cannot find the headername.h*** Means you got the -I parameter wrong (path of the include directory)

Comment: Paste the exact command that you invoke. In Windows there are many things that might go wrong, like file path naming conventions

Comment: To improve your question you will have to show actual details of what you tried and how it failed otherwise you are unlikely to get any help.

Comment: my Command:-
 g++ sdlm.cpp  -I{C:\SDL2-2.0.10\include} -L{C:\SDL2-2.0.10\lib\x86} -lmingw32 
 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

Comment: the error :-
sdlm.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL.h>

Comment: `-I{C:\SDL2-2.0.10\include}` I don't think you are supposed to use { or }

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\SDL2-2.0.10\lib\x86/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0x0): multiple definition of `main'; c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\SDL2-2.0.10\lib\x86/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0xa8): undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status